# How to check if a child component exists on a shallowWrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Let's say I have three components

```
const Foo = () => (<Text> Foo </Text>)
const Bar = () => (<Text> Bar </Text>)
const Parent = () => (<Text> Parent </Text>)
```

Now, I have a component that will wrap all these components like,

```
/*** Component.js ******/

class Component extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Parent>
          { this.state.showFoo && <Foo { ...fooProps }/> }
          { this.state.showBar && <Bar { ...barProps }/> }  
        </Parent>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, I want to write test cases using **jest** and **enzymes's shallow render**,

```
/**** jest_test.js *****/
//import required stuff

test("it renders Foo", () => {

  //This means Foo and Bar must be rendered
  const props = { someProp: "renderFooAndBar" }
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />);

  /*
  Now, I want to test based on the value of "someProp" if Foo and Bar rendered or not.
  I tried something like 

  wrapper.find("Foo"); 
  wrapper.find(Foo); 
  wrapper.find(<Foo />);

  but it always returned ShallowWrapper instance with length 0. 
  However, I would be able to see Foo and Bar on wrapper.html() method. 

  I also tried .dive(), .shallow(), .contains() methods but I didn't got the Foo and Bar node. 
  */
})
```

My first question, **Is my approach correct ?**

Second question, **How can I get the instance of Foo and Bar or some other deeply nested component in general ?**

Comment: After doing some configuration mentioned on docs, I managed to achieve this by using enzyme's mount. Thanks @Jai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to mention that ***Shallow*** renders only one level deep. It does not get deep down to render child components.

Instead I have to say that you should use ***mount***. It would render all the inner components too.

```
// you have to import mount from enzyme.
const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
```